# Solve f'[x]==0 for x

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried the following:

```
f[x_] := x^n/(k + x^(2 n));
Solve[f'[x] == 0, x]
```

But I got the following response:

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

```
f[x_] := x^n/(k + x^(2 n));
Solve[Simplify[f'[x]] == 0, x]

(* ==> {{x -> k^(1/(2 n))}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `Reduce` and limiting the domain (`Reals`) often produces more information:

```
ClearAll[f,x,n,k]

f[x_] := x^n/(k + x^(2 n))

sol = Reduce[f'[x] == 0, x, Reals];
```

The head of `sol` is `Or`; formatted to be more readable:

```
List @@ sol // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]